# cherry-pick a commit and keep original SHA code

Tags: git, commit, sha, cherry-pick

I would like to cherry-pick a commit on a fetched remote while keeping it's original SHA commit code (my current branch is based on this remote which I resetted to a previous state).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the commit hash really is.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the original SHA hash?

Comment: It's not an answer to the question but google brought me here with a similar problem, after which I found out that I'd actually want to do `git merge --ff-only [branch name]` rather than to `cherry-pick`.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar when keeping two repo in-sync, because that's a good way of knowing what commits are shared by both repos and figure out faster what are the commits that haven't been imported yet. Unfortunately, none of the solutions below work in such edge case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483037/git-good-practices-to-keep-a-forked-project-up-to-date-with-its-source-origin-wh

Answer (score 127, accepted):

A git SHA hash is computed from different pieces of information:

1. The **tree** it refers to; basically, the current content of the repository in the branch in which the commit appears.
2. The SHA of the **parent commit(s)**.
3. The **commit message**.
4. The **author information**: name, email and timestamp.
5. The **committer information**: name, email and timestamp.

Even if you edit a cherry-picked commit so that the tree, the commit message, the author and committer information are exactly the same, the SHA of the parent commit (or commits, if dealing with merge commits) will be always different. So, you will not be able to generate the same SHA hash after a cherry-pick (unless you find a SHA collision ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information :) in fact I created my branch with the command `git branch master remote/master` and that kept the original SHA's... then I resetted to a specific commit, and now I want to reset to another, more recent one but it goes to another point on the repo log...

Comment: In fact when I try to cp the commit I have a "deleted by us" error on all files related to it... that's weird...

Comment: BTW, committer will be different too.

Comment: "Even if you edit a cherry-picked commit so that the tree, the commit message, the author and committer information are exactly the same, the SHA of the parent commit (or commits, if dealing with merge commits) will be always different." 
This is not necessarily true. If you make a commit when opening a new branch, then create a second branch and cherry-pick from the first branch, then both commits would have the same parent. But they'd still have different SHAs in this case because the committer's commit time would be later on the cherry-picked commit.

Comment: @Vanuan Not if you cherry-pick your own commit.

Comment: @AamirRizwan timestamp would still be different, and that is part of committer information

Answer (score 27):

The SHA commit hash is made of from the state of the repository, using the whole history up to the point of the commit (branches not included). This means that you cannot keep the original hash on cherry-picking unless the whole history is the same, and in that case cherry-picking would make no sense.

Comment: It's the next commit on the repo log in fact, I tried to reset my local branch to the said commit's SHA but then my branch is in a whole different location...

Comment: Well, to be more precise, the SHA hash does not represent the _state of the whole repository_ but a _commit and its whole history_. The repository may well have different branches and commits…

Comment: @siegi thanks, added. "state of the whole repository in that point of time" was something I had in mind, but yeah, branches excluded too

Answer (score 8):

According to your comments to other answers I think you simply want to reset to some remote commit. You can use `git reset --hard <SHA>` to do this. **WARNING: This will *discard all of your (uncommitted) changes* in the working directory and all commits you did in this branch will no longer be accessible.**

If this is not what you want (or you are not sure) please describe more clearly what you did and what you want to do or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous for those who see only the command and just try it.

Comment: @chaosink, thanks for pointing this out, I tried to edit the answer to emphasise the potential data loss. Two remarks though: One should **_never_** blindly execute anything found on the internet without understanding it or at least being able to assess the implications of doing so. And second: You can recover at least the committed changes using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Answer (score 7):

Go into interactive rebase ("git rebase -i") and paste a new entry at the end with the exact revision you want to prepend to your HEAD.

Example:

Open an interactive rebase session:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

The screen now shows [something like] this:

```
pick efdd0ece Linked how to make a pull requests in README
pick 790a3be8 adjust pytest pins to fix testing infra
pick 5bb90d8f drop 3.4 support
pick 839dc8ba v2.22.0
pick b97fb61a Print the type of the password instead of the password itself
```

Your current HEAD is the last entry. Add a new entry to the bottom (just "pick" and your revision; no description necessary) with the exact revision that you want to prepend:

```
pick efdd0ece Linked how to make a pull requests in README
pick 790a3be8 adjust pytest pins to fix testing infra
pick 5bb90d8f drop 3.4 support
pick 839dc8ba v2.22.0
pick b97fb61a Print the type of the password instead of the password itself
pick 2a173c2a6491aae0772640ba7946a08315d18eb8
```

Save and close. That exact revision will now be your HEAD:

```
$ git log --oneline | head -n 6
2a173c2a Some commit
b97fb61a Print the type of the password instead of the password itself
839dc8ba v2.22.0
5bb90d8f drop 3.4 support
790a3be8 adjust pytest pins to fix testing infra
efdd0ece Linked how to make a pull requests in README
```

As mentioned in other answers, **you still have to follow the rules**. This works in only the very narrow case where you have the exact same branch, parents, and committer (such as with a code-review-centric process where you have a bunch of commits queued up somewhere, where the developers can push them up and bring them down without necessarily submitting them into the repository first); really only when the timestamps are the only thing that might have changed. In this case, you can force the identical revision in order to force the timestamps to be unchanged.

In most other cases, the parent will usually be different, and, this alone, means that your dream of forcing a certain revision will be dead. Git will always fix-up the revision to be correct if any of the non-timestamp factors are different.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find it mentioned in previous answers, so note that it's actually possible to preserve the original SHA if you are cherry-picking on top of the commit's parent, by adding the `--ff` flag.