# How to merge current local branch with specific single commit from different branch in remote repository?

Tags: git, commit, remote-access, git-merge, git-branch

Lets say I have this in my local:

```
master
branch-a
branch-b
```

and I have this in my remote repository:

```
master
branch-a
branch-b
branch-c
```

---

Conditions:

1. I own the remote repository. I have all needed accesses.
2. My local `branch-b` and remote `branch-b` already in sync.
3. Remote `branch-c` have a single commit with hash: `1ab2cd3`
4. Commit `1ab2cd3` is **NOT** the latest commit on remote `branch-c`.

Question: How can I merge my local `branch-b` with that `1ab2cd3` commit from remote `branch-c`?

Comment: If `1ab2cd3` is not the latest commit on *branch-c*, how can it be the single commit (only commit) on this branch?

Comment: @Matt Commits on remote `branch-c`: `HEAD`, `cmmt1`, `cmmt2`, `1ab2cd3` <<< I only want to merge `1ab2cd3`, not `HEAD`, `cmmt1`, or `cmmt2`. Does it make sense? Or should I change my 'single commit' term?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this properly... The term that most closely describes a *merge* of a single commit is *cherry-picking*. If you want to have the contents of commit `1ab2cd3` on *branch-b*, you could `git cherry-pick 1ab2cd3` while on *branch-b*. Note that this will give the commit a different commit-hash.

Comment: Is `git cherry-pick 1ab2cd3` mean I merge it from the remote _branch-c_? or the local _branch-c_? Is there a way to cherry-pick but not change the hash? @Matt

Comment: *Merging* is not really the right term to use in this scenario. *Cherry-pick* applies the changes introduced by the commit onto the current branch. This creates a new commit (new hash) and is not a *merge*. A commit is identified by its hash which is identical in your local repository and on the remote. When you cherry-pick this commit, it takes the commit no matter on what branch(es) it is part of. You cannot cherry-pick without changing the commit-hash (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676852)). The `-x` argument would put a reference to the original hash in the commit message.

Comment: I wrote an answer to your question as it seems my comments have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since my comments seem to have answered your question, I will add them as an answer:*

Merging is not really the right term to use in this scenario. The term that most closely describes a *merge* of a single commit is *cherry-picking*. If you want to have the **contents** of commit `1ab2cd3` on *branch-b*, you could use the following command while on *branch-b*:

```
git cherry-pick 1ab2cd3
```

*Cherry-pick* applies the changes introduced by the commit onto the current branch. This creates a new commit and is not a *merge* in terms of Git. Note that this will give the commit a different commit-hash. You cannot cherry-pick without changing the commit-hash (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676852/5024726)). However, the `-x` argument can be used to put a reference to the original hash in the commit message of the commit produced by cherry-pick:

```
git cherry-pick -x 1ab2cd3
```

Addressing your question concerning which branch the commit will be taken from: A commit is identified by its hash which is identical in your local repository and on the remote. When you cherry-pick this commit, it takes the commit no matter on what branch(es) it is part of.

Answer (score 1):

`git cherry-pick 1ab2cd3`

---

Thanks to @[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5024726/matt) for the explanation in question's comment section:

> Merging is not really the right term to use in this scenario.

> The term that most closely describes a merge of a single commit is **cherry-picking**.

> Cherry-pick applies the changes introduced by the commit onto the current branch. This creates a new commit (new hash) and is not a merge. A commit is identified by its hash which is identical in your local repository and on the remote.

> When you cherry-pick this commit, it takes the commit no matter on what branch(es) it is part of.

> You cannot cherry-pick without changing the commit-hash (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676852)). The -x argument would put a reference to the original hash in the commit message.

Comment: I actually put my comments into an answer since they seem to have solved your problem.